# Plotly.js not working after upgrading to Angular 13

Tags: angular, plotly, angular13

I have upgraded my Angular project from version 12 to version 13.
I use Plotly to create graphs and now I'm getting an error when starting the application:

`plotly.js:26321 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')`

After some research this seems to have something to do with the new way of packaging the application introduced with angular 13.
Does anyone have a solution how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the best option will be to import plotly.js via CDN.

https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js#plotly-via-cdn-module

We use the following version and it works just fine.
The latest (2.x.x) version doesn't work.

```
PlotlyViaCDNModule.setPlotlyVersion('1.58.5');
```